# Tipping angle of a box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, torque, statics

how do you calculate the tipping angle of a  box? That is the maximum angle a which a box can reach before tipping over. help, please!

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

Stability is lost if the center of gravity of the object goes over the pivot form which it is rotating. Googling stability + center of mass/gravity should yield lot of information on the subject.

[image]